# How do I format email outputs in Perl?

Tags: perl, forms

I am very new to writing in Perl.

I have a checkout pl which sends an email to the buyer with details of their order.  How do I format in Perl to display the order in a "pretty" format such as tables, coloured background images etc like in an html page???
This is the section of code I would like to format into something more attractive:

```
##-----Send email confirmation to the customer-----
open (MAIL,"|$mailprogram");
print MAIL "To: $b_email\n";
print MAIL "From: $oursalesemail\n";
print MAIL "Subject: Order Confirmation\n";
print MAIL "\n\n";
print MAIL "Hi $b_first\n";
print MAIL "\n\n";
print MAIL "Your order has been received.  A summary of your order appears below.\n";
print MAIL "\n";
&printMailFieldsFromForm;
print MAIL "\n";
print MAIL "Thank-you for your order.  It will be shipped posthaste.\n\n";
close MAIL;
```

Cheers
KD

Answer (score 1):

See [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email::Sender), [Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart) and [Email::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email::Simple).

You can use [Email::MIME::CreateHTML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email::MIME::CreateHTML) to create the message.

The [Perl Email Project](http://emailproject.perl.org/) web site seems a little dormant, but their [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/pep%40perl.org/) is active. You can also get help there.

I have the sinking feeling that you grabbed some ancient crap full of bad practices and security holes lying around on the web and you are processing CGI submissions manually as well. Please use [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple) or [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI).

Comment: I can't see anything in those Perldoc pages about how to format the email so it is "pretty" … or even anything (explict) about sending email in formats other than text/plain.

Comment: @David: I had forgotten the replacement for `Mime::Lite::HTML` and I was searching for it. In any case, I see you posted that while I was searching ;-) +1.

Comment: Don't people recommend against using CGI.pm?

Comment: @xenoterracide What do you mean? Who does? For what reason? I do recommend `CGI::Simple` over `CGI.pm` because it leaves out the functional interface and the HTML generation methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct two versions of the email. A plain text version (as you have now) and an HTML formatted version. Note that [email clients have a wide range of support for web standards](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) from very good to really poor.

Then you need to join them together into an email. I've had very good results using [Email::MIME::CreateHTML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::MIME::CreateHTML)  in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do all kinds of formatting with [Template](http://template-toolkit.org)::[Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Toolkit.pod), including emails. you might want to look into other templating engines too such as [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Template/lib/Text/Template.pm) of course if you don't need Unicode you could even consider the evil [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html). If you want HTML just write the html with template parts.